# Losing Grass tools after openlayers installation in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, openlayers-2, qgis-2.16

QGIS 2.16 is running well until I install the openlayers plugin. Then qgis loses the grass connection.

After deactivating or uninstallation everything works fine again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this problem is reproduceable, it should be a bug report rather than a question on GIS.SE

Comment: Could anybody check this out?

Comment: I was able to load an run r.reclass and densify algorithms after installing openlayers. Tested on a win10 64 and Nodebo OSGEO4w install

Comment: I have this issue with OSGEO4w and normal installation.

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15412

Comment: I do not have this issue on linux. You could probably replace openlayers by the quickmapservices plugin. Cheers,

Comment: I do also use the quickmapservices but I really like the forecast window before I load the background pics. Is there a dependency between openlayers and grass?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report and not a question for GIS.SE: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. After installing OpenLayers under QGIS 2.16.1 Nodebo (OSGEO4w installation on win7 64bit) the Grass tools worked, but when I restart QGIS they don't any more. The strange thing is, no matter which tool I try, the QGIS message bar always shows the same info text (see image) [![Executing algorithm `v.voronoi` - Creates a Voronoi diagram from an input vector][1]][1]

The only thing that helped was to deactivate the OpenLayers plugin again.

In the QGIS Log messages panel I get the following output:

```
2016-08-12T11:56:58 0   GRASS execution commands
        g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
        v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 dsn="C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tests\data" layer="points" output=tmp147099581862 --overwrite -o
        g.region n=4458983.8488 s=4458921.97814 e=270855.745301 w=270778.60198 res=100
        v.voronoi  input="tmp147099581862" output=outputd3df0586036642d89347ede417270b86 --overwrite
        v.out.ogr -s -c -e -z input=outputd3df0586036642d89347ede417270b86 dsn="C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\processingb71ddbbde3c1480f9a33e44ce07ba896\058ef868a1ce4e5abb222dba0e2bb3aa" format=ESRI_Shapefile olayer="output" type=auto
2016-08-12T11:56:58 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
            self.processAlgorithm(progress)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass\GrassAlgorithm.py", line 424, in processAlgorithm
            GrassUtils.executeGrass(commands, progress, outputCommands)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass\GrassUtils.py", line 289, in executeGrass
            env=grassenv
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
            errread, errwrite)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
            startupinfo)
        TypeError: environment can only contain strings

2016-08-12T11:56:58 1   There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

Comment: I also have this issue - it looks like it may have been to do with the install path not being correct. So have a look in Processing->Options->Providers-> GRASS GIS 7 Commands -> GRASS 7 folder. It looks like the bug could be with updating that path when a new version of GRASS is installed.

Comment: Same problem on QGIS version 2.18.2 - 32 bit Windows 7. GRASS plugins work once the Open Layers Plugin is disactivated.